# Calculated Column in Power BI using Paramaters in IF Statement

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax, measure

I am trying to create a custom column called "Min" and want the selected value for each parameter within the IF statement to output when the statement is true. Whenever I do the IF statement, it leaves the parameter value is a blank even though I designated a value within the parameter.

[image: Power BI screenshot]

I tired to create a calculated column and used a standard if statement in the picture attached.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have dynamic properties in calculated columns or calculated tables in DAX. These are only calculated exactly once at refresh time, and cannot be manipulated using slicer selections and similar functionality.